# I have 2 java installations /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java AND /usr/bin/java. I want to remove one (/usr/bin/java)

Tags: java, jdk

This is what i have, i want the top one gone

[image: Remove the top one]

Comment: So, what prevents you from reaching that goal?

Comment: I don't know which commands to run as i can't tell what names the packages go by

Comment: As it looks like you are running Ubuntu, you can run "dpkg-query -S /usr/bin/java to discover the package managing the file. You can then use "apt-get remove <package name>"

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). And at the very least, don't post images containing the wrong commands you ran! Also, you need to tell us what operating system you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is openjdk the other one is oracle java. So what you want to remove is opendjdk.

Assuming this is a .deb based system.

```
dpkg -l | grep openjdk
apt-get remove packagename
```

And then remove the packages that you find there. You could also instead of removing it just adjust your default used java with:

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

This way you can keep both installations and switch if you ever need the other one.

If it can't find the path to your wanted java you can add it manually by running e.g. this:

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java 3
```

And then the config command again.